# Battery Wattage hour requirement for 12v, 3.75 amp device?

Tags: voltage, batteries, amplifier, watts

My cpap machine resmed airsense 10 states the following numbers:

DC 24v,

3.75 A

As per my understanding the wattage required is 24 x 3.75 = 90

I am assuming WattHour is 90x1 = 90.

If I need to use it for 8 hrs, the battery backup should be 90 x 8 = 720wh

But most of the products have around 100wh claiming to last 8 hrs or more . What am I missing?

This example has 97wh only an promises 13 hrs.
https://document.resmed.com/documents/products/accessory/power-station-ii/user-guide/power-station-ii_user-guide_row_mul.pdf

Comment: It may be that it doesn't use 3.75 A continuously, but just as a peak when it turns on, or something like that--and under normal operation it needs only a fraction of that.

Comment: FYI For lithium ion batteries there are transport restrictions for > 100Wh.

Comment: sorry corrected voltage from 12V to 24V. So  24 x 3.75 = 90

Comment: @Hearth that seems like a reasonable explanation. I wish the manufacturer specified the average metrics also along with the peak, so we can make an estimation of how much wattHour we need in a backup battery.

Answer (score 1):

Many electronic appliances with motors require several times more current when starting up (for the first few seconds) than they do to run continuously.

To accurately calculate your power requirements, use an amp-hour or watt-hour meter to determine how many watt-hours the machine uses per hour.

Multiply that number by the desired runtime in hours to get the minimum required battery size. Since most batteries don't like being discharged to 0% repeatedly, get a slightly larger one.

Comment: Thanks @Thor. So does that mean what is specified on the device is the 'peak start up' metrics?

Comment: @Gadam When in doubt, measure it. I think so.